# ionic hide back button

Tags: ionic-framework

Is there a way to hide the back button in ionic? I try

```
$ionicConfig.backButton.icon('');
```

which couses unnecessary space in the bar. Via css I can hide it

```
.back-button { display: none; }
```

but the button still appears in the dom and this shouldn't. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question: It isn't the right way to do it via $ionicConfig. It works with $ionicNavBarDelegate. Here the code

```
$ionicNavBarDelegate.showBackButton(false);
```

Unfortunatly, it is only a combination of my code above. The button still exists in the dom.